# Filtering API responses as query params programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, query-string

I am trying to filter responses from the api in a node application by allowing the endpoint to take in query parameters.

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

const serverLogs = logs.data;
const urlQueryParams = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

//Looping through all logs
for(var i in serverLogs){
  var spd = serverLogs[i];
  level = spd.level;
  serverID = spd.serverId; 

  //console.log(serverID, level);
}

  console.log(`Log Level Query Param: ${urlQueryParams.level}`);
  res.end(JSON.stringify(serverLogs));
});
```

Programmatically, I would like to make the level query-able so when I hop in Postman, I can grab all the data by a specific level.

[Postman Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NT0o.png)

Any thoughts on how to approach?

Comment: I know this is probably a test, but looping over logs sounds very inefficient. If you want to make something for production you would need to store logs in a database like Elasticsearch.

Comment: Would help if you define your issue in more specific terms. How to approach what exactly? You can use Array#filter() if all you want is to filter the array by level

Comment: It's a simple test. I'm attempting to grab all data from the api based on level. So if I throw in the query params on PM that level=warn, all warn levels should show up. At the moment, the application can't do such.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Separate log acquisition from log filtering

Generally speaking, each routine should have one job and only one job. This is known as [the Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

It will help you get each part right, and it will also facilitate writing tests.

One place that may be good to draw a boundary would be to write a function that accepts a single log entry, and the filtering criteria, and returns a boolean indicating whether this entry satisfies the criteria. You can build all kinds of stuff atop this basic building block.

2. Consider using Streams for log access

Any pattern that relies on reading the entire log into RAM before filtering rows will yield bad performance. It's not clear from your snippet what `logs.data` is, but my guess is that it's the result of `FS.readFileSync` or similar. That loads the entire file into RAM and *then* lets you operate on it, and it will scale poorly.

Cehhiro's suggestion to use a DB will solve this by pushing the filtering into the DB engine, which relieves your node process of that work, but it has at least two consequences you may not like: (1) it limits you to the matching operations your DB supports, and (2) a DB is a heavyweight layer of complexity.

In my experience, logs are usually either written to disk as plain text, or transmitted to dedicated log stores via fire-and-forget messages (or sometimes both). I suspect you'll be dealing with log file on disk.

Node has good support for [Streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), which will let you scan log data efficiently without sacrificing the freedom to write filtering logic that suits your needs perfectly.

3. Use as many off-the-shelf components as you can

I actually wrote a [library for grokking a simple query syntax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/common-query-parser), which is perhaps a decent place to start. I designed it for a similar use-case, so it may fit your needs. Of course, if you don't like mine, there may be others out there that are satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks you kindly for the options.I tried writing a function, I tried querystrings. Streams is an option I really should look at, but I'll keep plucking away